# How to merge and get sum of the values two objects has same keys as objects

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have two object that needs to be flattened for a chart implementation.

```
2019-09-12: {
        type1: {
            subType1: {
                   value: 5
                      },
            subType2: {…}               
                },
        type2: {
             subType1: {
                   value: 8
                      },
            subType2: {…} 
               }
        }
```

this needs to turn into this;

```
cumulated: {
        subType1: {
               value: 13
                  },
        subType2: {sum}               
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge). For example

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Comment: the problem is I have everything as object there arent any array involved for me to use this

Comment: Also there are 2 levels of merging

Comment: Yes it also works. Can you just try that lodash function merge?

Comment: Looking at the original input and output, looks like the request was to combine the similar keys by summing them.

Comment: not the merge but merge with method worked. merge overwrites the values that needs to be summed however ive added this function to mergeWith() ```(objValue, srcValue, key, object, source, stack) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ objValue, srcValue }))
        if (typeof objValue === "number") return objValue + srcValue
      }``` and it works

Answer (score 1):

```
    var obj = {"2019-09-12": {
        type1: {
            subType1: {
                   value: 5
                      },
            subType2: {value: 7}               
                },
        type2: {
             subType1: {
                   value: 8
                      },
            subType2: {value: 9} 
               }
        }}
var sumType1 = 0;
var sumType2 = 0;
function cumul(){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(date){
  Object.keys(obj[date]).forEach(function(typeValue){
    sumType1 += obj[date][typeValue].subType1.value;
    sumType2 += obj[date][typeValue].subType2.value;
  })
})
return {
  cumulated: {
        subType1: {
               value: sumType1
                  },
        subType2: {sumType2}               
            }
}
}

console.log(cumul())
```

Comment: It works well, very different approach from what I was thinking, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the keys of the object and sum them.

```
const obj = {
  type1: {
    subType1: {
      value: 5
    },
    subType2: {
      value: 1
    },
  },
  type2: {
    subType1: {
      value: 8
    },
    subType2: {
      value: 2
    }
  }
};

const combine = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, cur) => {
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj[cur])) {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        res[key].value += obj[cur][key].value;
      } else {
        res[key] = obj[cur][key];
      }
    };
    return res;
}, {});

console.log(combine(obj));
```

Comment: works as intended, thank you! however, I am getting this warning from es-lint ```iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.``` this gives me a direction, only thing left to optimize it

Comment: You can try changing the `for (...)` to `Object.keys(obj[cur]).forEach(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody!
Here is what I ve come up with at the end:

I have used lodash library but its realy fast and clean. Also shape of the object is not important it can go as deep as your object goes

```
import mergeWith from 'lodash/mergeWith'

mergeWith({}, ...Object.values(objectThatNeedsToCollapse), (objValue, srcValue) =>
typeof objValue === "number" ? objValue + srcValue : undefined
)
```